Theorem - Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion
So in class, we have to fill in the chart.

I know that we can label the chart with 7 numbers, so that is where I started.

So after adding the numbers I tried breaking the question down into parts that would be more manageable. So reading the second part of the question I know that (A U B) would get 1,2,4,5,6,7 all shaded but because its not (A U B) only the outside would get shaded and 3.

Now looking at the first part of the question, I know that its not a, but the intersection of C. so it would look like this:

And because we know that it is just the intersection between the two halves it would just be section 3.

I think I got this done correctly, but I'm not too sure. I appreciate any help!!!
Thanks in advance

Your answer is correct.
Using DeMorgan's Law on $(A \cup B)^c$ gives $(A^c \cap B^c)$
Then altogether you have $(A^c \cap C) \cap (A^c \cap B^c)$ which is equivalent to $(A^c \cap C \cap B^c)$
So you are looking for where all of these areas intersect

